# Get containing component from nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a `ControlledInput` component, and in order to have access to the state of the component using `ControlledInput`, I have a `binder` prop in `ControlledInput`.

I'm having a slight issue when using the component:

```js
  render() {
    const CI = props => <ControlledInput binder={this} {...props} />;
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <h1>NEW RECIPE</h1>
        <ControlledInput binder={this} label={"Title"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The implementation above works completely fine. However, note the `const CI` I've defined. I tried to use this so I could just write `<CI label={"Title"}/>` without the `binder` since the `binder` will be the same on all the `ControlledInput` components I use in a given `render` method.

The problem with using `<CI label={"Title"}/>` is that when I type into the input, the input "blurs" and I have to reselect it. This appears to be because the `render` method creates the `CI` on every render.

I hope I've explained that clearly, because my head hurts.

Anyway, it makes sense to me why this happens. And I know that one solution is to put `const CI = props => <ControlledInput binder={this} {...props} />;` outside of the `render` function. But then I'd have to call it as `<this.CI>` and that starts to defeat the purpose.

And I can't put `CI` in global scope because then I don't have access to `this`.

### Is there a way to solve this?

## Update

Here is the current (very much in progress) code for `ControlledInput`:

```js
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";
type Props = {
  containerStyle?: Object,
  label: string,
  propName?: string,
  binder: Component<Object, Object>,
  onChange?: Object => void
};

class ControlledInput extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const propName = props.propName || props.label.toLowerCase();
    return (
      <div style={props.containerStyle}>
        <p>{props.label}</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          label={props.label}
          onChange={
            this.props.onChange ||
            (e => {
              props.binder.setState({ [propName]: e.target.value });
            })
          }
          value={props.binder.state[propName]}
        ></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The point of this whole endeavor is to simplify creating a form with controlled components, avoiding having to add `value={this.state.whatever}` and `onChange={e=>this.setState({whatever: e})}` to each one, which is not DRY in my opinion.

And then I want get a little more DRY by not passing `binder={this}` to every component and that's why I'm doing `const CI = props => <ControlledInput binder={this} {...props} />;`, which, again, has to be inside the class to access `this` and inside the `render` function to be called as `CI` rather than `this.CI`.

So that first explanation why you need to pass `this`, although I suppose I could also have props like `setState={this.setState} parentState={this.state}`, and in that case it does indeed start to make sense to combine those into something like `{...propsToSend}` as @John Ruddell suggested.

Note that I've provided a possibility to override `onChange`, and plan on doing so for most or all of the other props (e.g, `value={this.props.value || binder.state[propName]}`. If one were to override a lot of these (especially `value` and `onChange`) it would indeed make the component much less reusable, but the main use case is for quickly creating multiple inputs that don't have special input handling.

So, again, my ideal would be to call `<ControlledInput label="Title"/>` and have the component code take care of binding `state` and `setState` correctly. If this is possible. And then the second option would be to have a place to define the necessary context props in a place that makes it simple when it's time to actually use the component multiple times, like so:

```js
<ControlledInput label={"title"} {...contextProps}/>
<ControlledInput label={"author"} {...contextProps}/>
<ControlledInput label={"email"} {...contextProps}/>
<ControlledInput label={"content"} textArea={true} {...contextProps}/> // textarea prop not implemented yet, fyi
etc
```

I hear that accessing the parent state/context may be an anti-pattern, but there must be some way to do what I'm trying to do without using an anti-pattern, isn't there?

Comment: you can set a unique key so react wont unmount and remount. but why dont you just define a set of props that are generic `const propsToSend = { binder: this }` and then `const CI = ControlledInput`. And then use it `<CI {...propsToSend} label="Title" />`

Comment: It also feels weird that you would need to pass the class context to a child like this. Why do you need access to the state of the parent component? Why not just pass the relevant state that the input needs?

Comment: That first suggestion would work but takes us about the same amount of code as `binder={this}` so isn’t really better. As to your second question, the input needs to modify the state of its parent, that’s the whole point. I guess it would probably help if I include the code for `ControlledInput`! Will do tomorrow.

Comment: well, if passing `binder` is the only thing that is common, then sure. But if you have 4 common properties to send then it would be useful. The controlled input shouldn't be updating the state of the parent this way. You shouldn't be passing the context like this. Instead pass an `onChange` handler to your component, let the parent update its own state in that callback. the child can call that callback when the actual input change happens. Or you can make the input itself have the change logic. regardless you shouldn't be accessing parent state in this way, its an anti-pattern in React

Comment: I could see instances where you want inputs of other types, that should be something you can pass through as well (password type for login page for instance). Usually you would componetize your code so you use one input component for the whole website (unless theres a really good reason to not to), so it should be able to accept any type of input properties. [**Here's an example where you can make it dynamic and only have one onChange handler**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3tfgc). I put the field definition as a property on the class for the common unchanging data.

Comment: I see, pretty good example. And you could also pass other props to customize the input to your heart's content with `...props`. I guess your more proper version is worth the extra one or two props to pass.

Comment: Yea! Especially when you can use the same change handler for each input. It's not verbose in that way but still dynamic! This is the recommended way to do it in react :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the state of the parent, handle the state there and pass down the value to your input - `ControlledInput` won't have to know anything except how to handle data in and out. Something like this, and note that I jacked up the names a little so you can see which component is handling what:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Parent = () => {

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")

  const handleChangeInParent = (newTitle) => {
    setTitle((oldValue) => newTitle)
  }

  return(<div style={styles.container}>
    <h1>NEW RECIPE</h1>
    <ControlledInput handleChange={handleChangeInParent} label={title} />
  </div>)
}

const ControlledInput = ({handleChange, label}) => {
  return (
    <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={label} />
  )
}
```

If `ControlledComponent` needs to handle its own state, then pass it a default value and then have the `Parent` read the value when saving (or whatever):

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Parent = () => {

  const handleSaveInParent = (newTitle) => {
    console.log("got the new title!")
  }

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <h1>NEW RECIPE</h1>
      <ControlledInput handleSave={handleSaveInParent} initialLabel="Title" />
    </div>
  )
}

const ControlledInput = ({ handleSave, initialLabel }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(initialLabel)

  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    const value = ev.target.value
    setTitle((oldValue) => value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    handleSave(title)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={title} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

You shouldn't be sending `this` through - just send values and/or functions to handle values.

Comment: It seems like that would defeat the purpose, which is to have a reusable concise Controlled Input (for a form with several inputs) without having to provide change handlers (plus `value={this.state.whatever}`) for each input.

Comment: Something has to handle the state and change. Either the controlled input does, or the parent does. The more logic you put in the controlled input, the less reusable it becomes because it becomes more closely tied to a specific function rather than being generic and reusable. That’s not to say one way is right or wrong - it depends on your application. You can do it the first way, have the controlled input handle sanitization and empty or wrong values, add error messages, etc. I wouldn’t have a component just fill in a text input - that was just a simple example for structure purposes.

Answer (score 0):

### With Updated Implementation

#### (okay, John you win!)

Not positive if this is technically an "answer", but I've rewritten the component to take a `state` and **(updated)** a `setterFn` prop:

#### component

```js
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";
type Props = {
  containerStyle?: Object,
  labelStyle?: Object,
  label: string,
  propName?: string,
  state: Object,
  onChange?: Object => void,
  textArea?: boolean,
  setterFn: (key: string, value: mixed) => void
};

class ControlledInput extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const propertyName = props.propName || props.label.toLowerCase();
    const TagType = props.textArea ? "textarea" : "input";
    // only pass valid props to DOM element (remove any problematic custom props)
    const { setterFn, propName, textArea, ...domProps } = props;
    return (
      <div style={props.containerStyle}>
        <p style={props.labelStyle}>{props.label}</p>
        <TagType
          {...domProps}
          label={props.label} // actually could get passed automatically, but it's important so I'm leaving it in the code
          onChange={
            this.props.onChange ||
            (setterFn ? e => setterFn(propertyName, e.target.value) : null)
          }
          value={props.state[propertyName] || ""}
        ></TagType>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ControlledInput;
```

#### in use (somehow less code than before!)

```js
class Wrapper extends Component<Object, Object> {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const setterFn = (k, v) => this.setState({ [k]: v });
    const p = { state: this.state, setterFn: setterFn.bind(this) };
    return <ControlledInput {...p} {...this.props.inputProps} />
  }
}
```

I guess this is more appropriate. It still takes up a lot more space than `binder={this}`.

It doesn't actually the questions of:

1. How to access the parent's state from the component. Though from comments it seems like this is an anti-pattern, which I do understand from the theory of React.
2. How to set these repeating props elsewhere so that I can just call `. I guess the only solution is to do something like this:

```js
render() {
  const props = {state: this.state, setState: this.setState}
  <ControlledInput {...props} label="Title"/>
}
```

Which certainly isn't such a bad solution. Especially if I shorten that name to, say, a single character.

Much thanks to @John Ruddell for setting me on the right path.

Comment: Again you shouldn't be passing setState from one component to the other. this is an antipattern. setState is an internal method related to a single component, think of it as private. You shouldn't send it to other components. What happens if the child component has its own state too? then you have to call `props.setState` and `this.setState` in the same component. that can get messy real fast

Comment: That is indeed what I'd do if I needed to, but in this case I don't need `ControlledInput` to be stateful. I understand what you're saying (why it's an antipattern), but how would you propose accomplishing what I'm trying to do in a way that is usably concise? Your `map` version came close but unless I'm missing something (which I probably am) it requires all the components to be rendered the same (since they're iterated in the map)

Comment: You can control any properties when you map, which means you can render dynamic elements. Give me an example where you can't do something with that example I gave and I can help show how to do it correctly :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell please tell me you approve of my update!

Comment: Well, not completely lol. I posted an example of how I would do it. Your current answer is still passing the whole state object. Think about it this way, if you update the value of one of the inputs the others will re-render because of changing props (the whole state object). Yes you can do things to mitigate this issue in the component itself. But its better to just be **explicit**. Just pass what you need to the component (like a value and a change handler). Make the input component dumb rather than complicated. It makes your test cases for components more streamlined and directive.